# How to make yii2 query using where() - andWhere()?

Tags: yii2, query-builder

I have make one query using conditional statement.

```
$query = Student::find()
            ->where('status=1');

            if(isset($params['standard_id']) AND !empty($params['standard_id'])){
                $query->andWhere(["standard_id"=>$params['standard_id']]);
            }
            if(isset($params['section_id']) AND !empty($params['section_id'])){
                $query->andWhere(["section_id"=>$params['section_id']]);
            }
            if(isset($params['year']) AND !empty($params['year'])){
               $query->andWhere(["year"=>$params['year']]);
            }
            //$result = $query->all();

        return $query;
```

**Mysql**

```
select *from student where satus=1 and standard_id=3 and section_id=1 and year=2015
```

If possible to make using where - `andWhere` in yii2?

please help me

Comment: What's the problem in above code, yes you can use it

Comment: Well you have to first store params  in variable then you can apply @sarin's answer.

Comment: I have notice about your `if` condition. You can use either isset or empty. No need to use both.

Comment: Consider using [`andFilterWhere`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#andFilterWhere%28%29-detail). That way you don't even need to check if a variable is set: `Student::find()->where(['status' => '1'])->andFilterWhere(['standard_id' => $params['standard_id'])`...

Answer (score 4):

Try this.can't understand your question clearly. may be this will help you.

```
$model = User::find()
    ->where('satus> :satus', [':satus' => '1'])
    ->andWhere('standard_id= :standard_id', [':standard_id' => 3])
    ->andWhere('section_id= :section_id', [':section_id' => 1])
    ->andWhere('year= :year', [':year' => 2015])
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use both `where()` and `andWhere()`. This should helps you to understand how it works.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/QueryTrait.php#L101